# Unable to sent Header elements in a rest get call from Typescript

Tags: typescript, rest, http-headers, angular-http

My Code is :-

```
accountBalance(response: any): Observable<any> {
          
        const header = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

        
        return this.http.get('api/account/balance',{headers : header})
            .pipe(
                map(this.extractData),
                catchError(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return of(false);
                }));
    }

private extractData(res: Response): any {
        const body = res;
        return body || { };
      }
```

But this request is not carrying the **Authorization** token. I am not able to understand mu fault. Please suggest.

`String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");`

In REST API, the above part is coming as **NULL**.

Comment: Please note that the tag "angularjs" refers to AngularJS 1.x, not Angular 2+.

Comment: You are passing `token` variable but where it is declared or initialized ? I think the value of token is `null`

Comment: Its not null, I have checked it by **Console.log**.